# JPA @ManyToMany with a common join column

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I have the following three tables:

**quizes**

- quiz_id

**questions**

- quiz_id
- question_id

**answers**

- quiz_id
- answer_id

**questions_answers**

- quiz_id
- question_id
- answer_id

Questions have a composite PK consisting of quiz_id and question_id. Answers also have a composite PK consisting of quiz_id and answer_id.

Each quiz has its own questions and answers, and these questions and answers match each other in a many-to-many relationship (in a scope of a quiz). I know it sounds a bit strange but a question may have several answers and one answer may relate to different questions, too.

I'm trying to implement this relationship in my QuestionEntity. Here's the relevent part of my class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "questions")
public class QuestionEntity implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private QuestionPK primaryKey = new QuestionPK();

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "questions_answers",
            joinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "quiz_id", referencedColumnName = "quiz_id"),
                    @JoinColumn(name = "question_id", referencedColumnName = "question_id")
            },
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "quiz_id", referencedColumnName = "quiz_id"),
                    @JoinColumn(name = "answer_id", referencedColumnName = "answer_id")
            }
    )
    private List<AnswerEntity> keys = new ArrayList<AnswerEntity>();
}
```

I get the following error at compile time:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for collection: ru.andrewquiz.dao.quiz.QuestionEntity.keys column: quiz_id
```

Does it mean that I will have to create in my questions_answers table 2 separate columns: question_quiz_id and answer_quiz_id? Although in my example they will always contain a reference to the same quiz?

**EDIT:**
I've looked at the example suggested by @XtremeBaumer: [link](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/). Tried to implement it, introduced QuestionsAnswersEntity.class and changed other classes according to the example. My QuestionsAnswersEntity class is declared like the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "questions_answers")
@AssociationOverrides({
        @AssociationOverride(name = "primaryKey.question",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "quiz_id", referencedColumnName = "quiz_id"),
                @JoinColumn(name = "question_id", referencedColumnName = "question_id")}),
        @AssociationOverride(name = "primaryKey.answer",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "quiz_id", referencedColumnName = "quiz_id"),
                @JoinColumn(name = "answer_id", referencedColumnName = "answer_id")})
})
public class QuestionsAnswers implements Serializable {...}
```

However this doesn't seem to make much difference to my problem since hibernate is again complaining about my quiz_id column being part of a foreign key to two different tables. I get the same error as previously.

Comment: look at this [example](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/)

Comment: I don't really understand the structure. Should be a manytomany Quiz to Questions . Forgetting about Answers for now I would expect tables quizzes (id, name, date etc.), questions (id, subject, text etc) and quiz_questions (the join table quiz_id, question_id).

Comment: @AlanHay No, quizes to questions is one to many; and quizes to answers is one to many. Answers to questions is many to many.

Comment: @AlanHay For each quiz there is a set of answers and a set of questions. There are different types of quizes (think of them as tests. Didn't want to use 'test' word in code). In some types each question has its own set of possible answers (multiple choice options). But in others, you are required to fill in the gaps with options from a set of options provided for the whole quiz. There are other types of quizes, too. So, generally questions to answers should be many to many. At least that's the best I could come up with.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer tried it, didn't quite help. I've updated the main post.